# Compute $\mathbb P(\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}|B_s|\leq t)$.

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let $B$ a Brownian I want to compute $$\mathbb P(\sup_{0\leq s\leq t} |B_s|\leq \sqrt t).$$

I tried as follow : $$\mathbb P(\sup_{0\leq s\leq t} |B_s|\leq t)=\mathbb P(\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s\leq \sqrt t, \inf_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s>-\sqrt t )\leq \mathbb P(\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s\leq \sqrt t)=\mathbb P(|B_t|\leq \sqrt t),$$
and this can be easily computed. But the bounded is a bit to coarse. Is there a better way to have a tighter upper-bound ?

Comment: Maybe doob inequality ?

Comment: Denote by $M_t = \sup_{s \leq t} B_s$ and $m_t = \inf_{s \leq t} B_s$ the running maximum and minimum, resp., then $$\mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \leq t} |B_s| \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(M_t \leq t, m_t \geq -t).$$ The joint distribution of $(M_t,m_t)$ is known and one gets $$\begin{align*}& \mathbb{P}(\sup_{s \leq t} |B_s| \leq t) \\ &=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{-t}^t \left[ \exp \left(- \frac{(z+4kt)^2}{2t} \right)- \exp \left(- \frac{-(z-2t+4kt)^2}{2t} \right) \right] \,dz. \end{align*}$$ (see e.g. Handbook of Brownian motion) Not sure whether this is of any use for you